# Is there any better solution to avoid my "memory exceeded" error in hackerearth

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, dynamic-memory-allocation

```
int **list, **short_list;
//num defines the number of rows and 2 defines no. of column needed
list = malloc(num * 2 * sizeof(int *));
short_list = malloc(num * 2 * sizeof(int *));

for(i = 0; i < num; i++){
    list[i] = malloc(num * 2 * sizeof(int));
    short_list[i] = malloc(num * 2 * sizeof(int));
}
```

Though I have created dynamic memory allocation using pointers to array, undergone "Memory Limit exceeded" error to few of my outputs in hackerearth. Is this way of memory allocation is wrong.

Comment: Simply use `int (*list) [y] = malloc( sizeof(int[x][y]) ); ... free(list);`. Everything else is various degrees of incorrect or bad practice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is something wrong with your allocation. In the first `malloc` you get `num * 2` pointers but in the loop you only initialize `num` of these pointers. That is for sure a bug.

Further it seems strange that you inside the loop uses `num * 2` again. That means you end up allocating `num * num * 2` integers. That is most likely not what you want.

If you really want the matrices to be `num * 2` simply do:

```
int **list, **short_list;
//num defines the number of rows and 2 defines no. of column needed

list = malloc(num * sizeof(int *));            // Only use num here
short_list = malloc(num * sizeof(int *));

for(i = 0; i < num; i++){               
    list[i] = malloc(2 * sizeof(int));         // Only use 2 here
    short_list[i] = malloc(2 * sizeof(int));
}
```

Another and simpler way to allocate a `num * 2` matrix is:

```
int (*list)[2];
list = malloc(num * sizeof *list);
```